# Displaying data from DB in a table. Android

Tags: android

I am looking for a simple way to display data from DB on the phone screen. Best I would like to create a table (not DB table, but table on the screen) which would display all the data I want. Is there any easy way to do it? The only idea I have is by using custom listView, but I'm not sure it will work as I want it to. I don't want to be able to interact with a table, just to be able to display the data.

Comment: Custom `ListView` sounds good to me. But I don't know what you want it to be like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CursorAdapter` to bind the queried `Cursor` to your `ListView`. Make sure you query for the `Cursor` on a background thread with a `CursorLoader` for the most responsive user experience.